# How validate my attachments in rich text on Action Text Rails 6?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actiontext

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
    has_rich_text :content

    validates :content, presence: true
    validate :content_length
    validate :content_embeds

    def content_embeds
       if content.embeds.any?
           errors.add(:content, 'Нельзя загружать более 4 изображений') if content.embeds.size > 4
           content.embeds.each do |attach|
               errors.add(:content, 'Изображение не может весить > 10 мБ') if attach.byte_size > 1242880
               errors.add(:content, 'Можно загружать только изображения') unless attach.image? 
               errors.add(:content, 'Недопустимый формат изображения') unless attach.content_type == 'image/jpeg' || attach.content_type == 'image/png'
            end
        end
    end 

    def content_length 
        max_length = 50
        symbol_size = 0

        if content.embeds.any? 
           content.embeds.each do |attach|
              symbol_size += (attach.filename.size + 2)
           end
        end

        errors.add(:content, 'Слишком длинный текст') if (content.to_plain_text.size - symbol_size) > max_length  
        content.embeds.each { |attach| puts "ATTACH #{attach}"}
    end
```

How i can check my attachments if `content.embeds` is empty, even when i attach images? But when i use `content.embeds` in my views, it shows my images. Sorry for my English. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Answer in down
    **rich_text_content.body.attachments**
Return attachments when creating model, i can use it for valid.